# Execute QTP/UFT test cases using Python or from command prompt

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line, qtp, hp-uft

Is is possible to execute QTP/UFT test cases from Python source code or from command prompt, can anyone explain please?

Comment: Might be a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13907603/how-can-i-run-a-qtp-test-from-the-command-line